# Android ADB from JavaScript Webpage

Tags: javascript, android, adb

I have a problem with a simple web app on android.
I simply have to make a web page in JavaScript that prints messages or performs callback functions based on the key pressed.

The problem lies in the device on which it should run, that is an Android TV and the keys to which I should associate callback function are those of remote control. The TV manufacturer told me that the only way to get information about the buttons pressed on the remote control is through ADB, specifically through the command “adb logcat”.

So my question is: is it possible from JavaScript in the browser to read the output of the command abd (adb logcat)? Or in some way have the information returned by ADB on the web page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: I haven't done any more tests yet because the TV manufacturer told me that this is the way to go. Do you have any way suggestions to do?